# DQL select association

Tags: php, database, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, dql

I have 2 doctrine entity's,

entity `A` has a field `name`

entity `B` has a field `city`

entity `A` has a one to many association to entity `B` named `bees`

Now i try to select all `A` entity's that have a name like 'test' or has a association to a `B` entity that has a city like 'test'

the DQL i have:

`SELECT a FROM A a INNER JOIN a.bees b WHERE a.name LIKE ?1 OR b.city LIKE ?1`

This works when `A` has a associated `B` but if there is no associated `B` the result is empty even if the name of `A` matches.

How do i fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a left join

```
SELECT a FROM A a LEFT JOIN a.bees b WHERE a.name LIKE ?1 OR b.city LIKE ?1
```

Here is a cheat sheet: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Visual_SQL_Joins/Visual_SQL_JOINS_orig.jpg